# UICollectionView - attempt to delete and reload the same index path

Tags: ios, objective-c, photos, photokit

This is `PHPhotoLibraryObserver`

```
- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
        if (collectionChanges) {
            self.assetsFetchResults = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];
            if (![collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges] || [collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
                [self.collectionView reloadData];
            } else {
                // if we have incremental diffs, tell the collection view to animate insertions and deletions
                [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                    NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
                    if ([changedIndexes count]) {
                        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[changedIndexes indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                    NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
                    if ([removedIndexes count]) {
                        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[removedIndexes indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                    NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
                    if ([insertedIndexes count]) {
                        [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[insertedIndexes indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                    }
                } completion:nil];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I get error after deleting photos in other apps

This is an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete and reload the same index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'

when i sort `PHFetchResult` as follows. crash as above

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
self.assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
```

when i set sort options to nil. go well

```
self.assetsFetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:nil];
```

I'm not sure what's wrong..

Answer (score -1):

Filter out indexes which you've deleted before trying to reload them:

```
NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [changeDetails changedIndexes];
NSMutableIndexSet *safeChangedIndexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

// Filter out indexes that we've deleted
[changedIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
{
    if (![removedIndexes containsIndex:index])
    {
        [safeChangedIndexes addIndex:index];
    }
}];
[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[safeChangedIndexes indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
```